# Unable to connect to Docker Redis (Redis is up and running)

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I am trying to use redis with my existing python app. Everything starts fine, however, whenever I try to go in 127.0.0.1:4123 (aka index page), I am getting connection refused error.

Here is my docker-compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: backend_server/
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 5
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      # service update configuration
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
        failure_action: continue
        monitor: 60s
        max_failure_ratio: 0.3
    depends_on:
      - "redis_cache"
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis_cache
      - REDIS_PORT=5789 
    volumes:
      - /home/$USER/.raster/:/app/_images/
    ports:
      - "7777"
    networks:
      - backend_bridge
    restart: always
    command: ["python", "prod_run.py"]

  nginx:
    build:
      context: nginx/
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - "backend"
    ports:
      - "4123:80"
    networks:
      - backend_bridge
    restart: always

  redis_cache:
    build:
      context: redis/
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    volumes:
      - /home/$USER/.redis/:/data
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - backend_bridge
    ports:
      - "5789:5789"

networks:
  backend_bridge:
    driver: bridge
```

I am using **docker-compose up --build** command to test on the local machine. (I know that deploy commands won't work. They are for swarms).

Here is the message I am getting when I try to visit 127.0.0.1:4123

`redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to redis_cache:5789. Connection refused.`

What am I doing wrong? TIA

========================

Update #1

I ran the redis image using **docker run** command exposing the port and use **redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5555**, it connected. However I get the following message for **ping**

```
127.0.0.1:5555> ping
Error: Connection reset by peer
127.0.0.1:5555>
```

Comment: 5789 isn't the ordinary Redis port.  What's in your `redis/Dockerfile`?

Comment: I used 5789 on redis_conf file. Also, I have fixed it and the result is on the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer to this problem was hidden deep inside a github issue

https://github.com/docker-library/redis/issues/45#issuecomment-219140550

Long story short, I had to remove the bind addresses and turn protected-mode to no.

It worked. Cheers